# Clearing up confusions with limits and colimits of functors

Tags: category-theory, definition, limits-colimits

$\DeclareMathOperator{\colim}{colim}$ I've been having trouble making sense of various notational / conventional aspects of limits.

The first introduction I had with them was with a set of lectures notes by Schapira, where he defines the colimit of a functor $F: I\to C$ and the limit of a functor $G:I^{op}\to C$. The way he introduces limits/colimits is as an object representing a functor $I^{op}\to Set$. So first he defines what a projective limit (of a functor $I^{op}\to Set$) is in $Set$ and then (keeping the notations above) takes $\colim F$ and $\lim G$ to be (if they exists), objects representing the functors $X\mapsto Hom_{C}(F(-),X)$ and $X\mapsto Hom_{C}(X,G(-))$. From this I sort of internalised that you take the colimit of a functor $I\to C$ and the limit of a functor $I^{op}\to C$, but that the limit of $I\to C$ wouldn't make sense.

But when you look at the definition with universal cones/cocones, say from Riehl's book, nothing prevents me from taking the limit / colimit of the same functor, simply by looking at cones under or over the given functor, and I've read examples where one actually does that. But with my original definition, it's not given that you can take the limit of $F:I\to C$, only the colimit. Even simply when thinking of functors as diagrams, it's obvious you should be able to have both a limit and colimit of the same diagram, but I'm not sure how to deal with that with the first definition.
I'm pretty sure Schapira's right with his definition and I just don't understand how to reconcile both.Maybe this stems from the fact that $Fun(C,D)^{op}\simeq Fun(C^{op},D^{op})$, I'm not sure.

Comment: $I=(I^{op})^{op}$, so you can think of every category as an opposite category. It's really just a matter of keeping track of index conventions at the end of the day. For example, if our index set is the natural numbers, we wanna take a colimit of a diagram that looks like $X_0\rightarrow X_1\rightarrow X_2\rightarrow\dotsc$, but we wanna take a limit of a diagram that looks like $\dotsc\rightarrow X_2\rightarrow X_1\rightarrow X_0$, so even though the objects in the index category are the same, in terms of the arrows it's most natural to consider them opposite.

Comment: You *can* take the limit of a diagram that looks like $X_0\rightarrow X_1\rightarrow X_2\rightarrow\dotsc$, but this is a trivial case: the limit is just $X_0$. Analogously for the colimit. So I would assume Schapira introduces the notions like that, because that's most in line with how you will actually end up applying limits/colimits.